Mocking a library that has 2 different paths/packages in jest
I was figuring out how to mock a library that has 2 different paths for example
@floating-ui/react-dom and @floating-ui/dom that belongs to the same library
When I mock @floating-ui/dom it seems to be that @floating-ui/react-dom is also mocked and viceversa
I'm trying to mock @floating-ui/dom but keep the @floating-ui/react-dom as the actual implementation
Here is my approach but without any results
jest.mock('@floating-ui/dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@floating-ui/dom'),
  computePosition: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({})
}));

jest.mock('@floating-ui/react-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@floating-ui/react-dom')
}));

I was expecting to mock them standalone.
